# How to call Stored Procedure that just uses a SELECT

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc

I'm replacing some code by previous developers, and need to compare my results with the old results.

The previous code was a bunch of MS SQL stored procs, and essentially, it just returns 1 or 0.
But the last thing it does is

```
select key, cd,  descr, sum(quantity) quantity, sum(price) price
from ##output
```

and I don't have access to the C# code calling it, so I am not sure how this works.  Its result is 0 or 1, but it also manages to return those 5 fields from the select.

There aren't any OUT parameters.  How is one supposed to get at the results of a SELECT in a stored procedure (in Java/JDBC/JPA/any method)?

I've tried a few things with both the jTDS and SQLServer drivers.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax that you use is `insert into . . . exec`.  Something like:

```
insert into t(col1, . . . coln)
    exec sp_stored_procedure ;
```

This will store the results from the stored procedure into the table.  The table needs to be predefined, which means that you need to know the columns in advance and will get an error if they are not correct.  The [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776381%28v=sql.105%29.aspx#OtherTables) for `insert` contains more examples and information.

I think that using such a procedure is a bad way to return result sets from stored procedures.  In many cases, such stored procedures can be replaced with user defined functions that return tables.

Erland Sommerskog has an excellent [blog](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html) on passing data between stored procedures in SQL Server, explaining the benefits and downsides to several methods.

Comment: hrm, my goal is to get the results back to Java so I can benchmark and compare my results to the stored proc's results.  So if I need to use another table, then every test, I'll be clearing the table, inserting new values into it, and then selecting from the table, which is not fair for benchmarking.  I presume the code works from a SQL perspective, but I'm wondering if there's any direct way to get the SELECT output back to Java without this intermediary table that needs to be cleared each time?

Comment: @djb . . . I would use a table variable for this purpose.  But the central point is that having stored procedures return tables like this is a bad design.  Perhaps the procedure should return a string that contains a SQL statement, and then you can run the SQL statement in your application.

Comment: Well I'll put the data into a temp table and select from the table, that works... I'm just wondering, are OUT variables the only sanctioned method for returning multiple data fields from a stored proc?  Why is this method possible, and is it just for the sake of having an INSERT/EXEC combo?  (i.e. Why is there no SELECT/EXEC combo?)

Comment: @djb . . . SQL Server is unusually in having stored procedures that "return" the values from embedded `select` statements.  I would check to see if your stored procedure can really be a table valued function (if you use dynamic SQL or certain other constructs, then this is not possible).

Comment: Ok, thanks.  We're actually replacing the stored procedure altogether.  But I'll keep table valued functions in mind as an alternative for out variables.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM proc1(?)");
ps.set...
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Doesn't work...  Stored procedures are called with CallableStatement.  Trying your code says Invalid object name 'proc1', (whereas it finds it with a CallableStatement).